# Why is my third div bolting out of the bottom of the page when the height of the second div changes, and how do I fix it?

Tags: html, css

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewlouis93/7pNGB/). Now note, how the third div goes awry once you use the `Damper Type` dropdown menu.

Is there any way to hold it in place without using absolute positioning? Or would that be my best bet in this case?

In addition, I feel like my understanding of relative positioning is on shaky grounds, because I did not understand what would make the div defined by `#elastic_period` do that.

Note for anyone looking at the JSFiddle: The important CSS should be around lines 330. The code written to describe that page is upto line ~330. The rest of the CSS are bootstrap css documents.

Comment: You firstly need to work out how you want the page to be displayed. It's not clear from the example. Think both of wide pages and narrow pages.

Comment: It's supposed to be three columns. The first holding the buttons, the second holding the diagram when an option in selected, and the third is a form. As the browser changes in size (I assume going from narrow to wide or vice versa), the divs are scaled... Does that somewhat clear any haziness?

Comment: There are various options. For example, set each box to float: left and set a minimum width on their container.

Comment: I gave this a shot, when the size of the second column changes (due to the div being displayed onclick), the third column seems to dip down...